# Preventing code duplication in jQuery

Tags: php, jquery

I have two selects on a page.  When either is changed, I use jQuery AJAX to post the values to a PHP script and return the results, which I then place on the page.

I want this to run on document ready too, but I don't know the most elegant, or 'proper' way to do it.  Presumably, wrap part of it in a function and call it on document ready; if this is the case, how would I do it?  At the moment, the code is duplicated (see below).

Thank you

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){

            $("#results").html('Searching...');

                var foo = $("#foo").val();
                var bar = $("#bar").val();

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "ajax_script.php",
                data: "foo=" + foo + "&bar=" + bar ,

                success: function(msg){

                if(msg == 'nil')
                     { 
                     $('#results').html('No results');
                     } 
                    else 
                    {
                        $('#results').html(msg);
                    } 

                } // complete AJAX success

            }); // complete AJAX


            $("#foo, #bar").change(function(){        
            $("#results").html('Searching...');

            var foo = $("#foo").val();
            var bar = $("#bar").val();

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "ajax_script.php",
                data: "foo=" + foo + "&bar=" + bar ,

                success: function(msg){

                    if(msg == 'nil')
                     { 
                     $('#results').html('No results');
                     } 
                    else 
                    {
                     $('#results').html(msg);
                    } 

                } // complete AJAX success

            }); // complete AJAX
        });

    });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put that whole ajax in one function like

```
function my_ajax() {
     $("#results").html('Searching...');

            var foo = $("#foo").val();
            var bar = $("#bar").val();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "ajax_script.php",
            data: "foo=" + foo + "&bar=" + bar ,

            success: function(msg){

                if(msg == 'nil') { 
                   $('#results').html('No results');
                } else {
                   $('#results').html(msg);
                } 
            } // complete AJAX success
        }); // complete AJAX
}
```

And call the function on `dom ready` and `on change` like

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      my_ajax();              //On DOM ready
      $("#foo, #bar").on('change',function(){        
           my_ajax();
      });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you should create one function and move all the code into that function and call that function onChange event. see example below:

JS:

```
$(function(){
    myFunction();
    $("#foo, #bar").change(myFunction);
});
function myFunction(){
    $("#results").html('Searching...');

            var foo = $("#foo").val();
            var bar = $("#bar").val();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "ajax_script.php",
            data: "foo=" + foo + "&bar=" + bar ,

            success: function(msg){

            if(msg == 'nil')
                 { 
                 $('#results').html('No results');
                 } 
                else 
                {
                    $('#results').html(msg);
                } 

            } // complete AJAX success

        }); // complete AJAX
}
```

Comment: i don't know why people are down voted the answer. what is the wrong with this answer?

Answer (score 0):

You could also use `trigger` like so:

```
    $("#foo, #bar").change(function() {
        $("#results").html('Searching...');

        var foo = $("#foo").val();
        var bar = $("#bar").val();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "ajax_script.php",
            data: "foo=" + foo + "&bar=" + bar ,

            success: function(msg) {
                if(msg == 'nil') {
                    $('#results').html('No results');
                } else {
                    $('#results').html(msg);
                }
            }
        })
    }).trigger('change');
```

That way it is triggered on document ready (if you put it with the document ready) and still able to use it when your selects change.